# How to default order results of belongsTo relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
//model User 
class User extends Eloquent { 
    public function post() { 
        return $this>hasMany('Post'); 
    } 
} 

//model Post 
class Post extends Eloquent { 
    public function user() { 
        return $this->belongsTo('User'); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships):

> Since, like Eloquent models themselves, relationships also serve as
>   powerful query builders, defining relationships as functions provides
>   powerful method chaining and querying capabilities.

So, do this:

```
class User extends Model
{
public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post')->orderBy('field_name');
    }
}
```